# How to create a new Pandas column based on group ID and percentage of first value?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

This is original input dataframe.

[Input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xDIh.jpg)

This is the expected output dataframe. Please help, thanks.

[Output dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1CI1.jpg)

Comment: we can't understand it. it is not a apropiate format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```py
>>> df["Age_first"]=df.join(df.groupby(df["Name"]).agg({"Age":"first"}), on="Name", rsuffix="_2")[["Age_2"]]
>>> df["Ratio"]=df["Age"]/df["Age_first"]
>>> df
  Name  Age  Age_first  Ratio
0    A    2          2    1.0
1    A    3          2    1.5
2    A    1          2    0.5
3    B   10         10    1.0
4    B    8         10    0.8
5    B   12         10    1.2
>>> df = df.drop("Age_first", axis=1)
>>> df
  Name  Age  Ratio
0    A    2    1.0
1    A    3    1.5
2    A    1    0.5
3    B   10    1.0
4    B    8    0.8
5    B   12    1.2
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works for you

```
df['ratio']= df.groupby('Name')['Age'].apply(lambda x : (x.count()/x.sum())*x)
```

Comment: Then, please up-vote & accept the answer

Comment: Sorry, I just found something is wrong with your solution.